# Making @username point to user's profile

Tags: feature-request, display-names

We use @username in comments and other places to refer to others here on stack exchange communities , so I guess  it would be good if @username automatically points to the profile to user 'username'.

Comment: Given 99.9% of the time there is little confusion who is being replied too, why is this necessary?  Couldn't someone interested in knowing who was being replied too find the name in the comments?

Comment: There's a non-zero chance of creating broken links here for users who end up deleting their profiles for whatever reason. Having no links is better, IMO.

Comment: I am not quite sure whether this functionality is already there or not :-whenever someone  uses  `@your_user_name`  somewhere then getting a notification like `@another_user_name` referred you in their post rather than the generic one another_user also  commented is better.

Comment: @charany1 I'm not sure what you're referring to there. If it's a different request (or a support question), please post it separately.

Comment: if @user12345 is already part of a conversation you'll find a link to their profile in one of their earlier posts. The only confusion starts when a user is @-replied but removed all their comments from a post, in which case that user decided to be no longer be involved in that thread, hence the need to visit the specific profile is also reduced.

Comment: A better suggestion could be to link to the comment it's a reply to.

Comment: @Tim , yeah that's kinda better.

Comment: @charany1 you could make a new fr, but again it may not be accepted - comments are often removed.

Answer (score 0):

It might be nice, but if i want to ping @Joe in this post, which one of the [66 Joes on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?page=1&tab=reputation&filter=month&search=joe) will it link to? Because usernames aren't unique, the system can't know who to link to. You'll just have to do it manually.

Comment: Well, the system does know who actually got/will get the notification.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I interpreted the feature request as being for in posts. Was that wrong?

Comment: Oh my, you're probably right. :/